# Need to provide extra suggestions with Datetime prompt to use in bot framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, prompt, azure-bot-service

Along with datetime prompt I am trying to pass extra suggestions but choices in prompt object is not working. Can anyone suggest a way to pass extra suggestions along with date time prompt.

Solution tried:

```js
async flightBookingDate(step) {
    if (destinationProvidedForFlightBooking) {
        step.values.destination = "Delhi";
    } else {
        step.values.destination = step.result;
    }

    if (!step.values.flightBookingDate) {
        await step.context.sendActivity("Below are the suggested date options?")
        var reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Today', 'Tomorrow']);
        await step.context.sendActivity(reply);

        let prompData = {
            prompt: "For when you want to book flight?",
            retryPrompt: "No flights avaliable for today. Please enter different date"
        }

        return await step.prompt(DATETIME_PROMPT, prompData)
    } else {
        return await step.continueDialog()
    }
}
```

after executing bot below is the output:

[image]

can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you know this, but the suggested actions are disappearing because you're sending another message after the suggested actions. Are you asking for a way to keep the suggested actions from disappearing, or are you asking for an alternative to suggested actions? What channel are you making this bot for?

Comment: I am looking for an alternative of suggested action. I am using bot emulator.

Comment: I could have asked "What channel are you using?" but I was worried you were going to say Emulator so I specifically asked "What channel are you making this bot for?" Do you really expect your customers to install Bot Framework Emulator to talk to your bot? Please do not say Emulator when someone who's trying to help you asks what channel you're using, and actually provide the information they need in order to help you.

Comment: I would be using Microsoft teams

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that [Teams does not support suggested actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference#action-support-by-channel).

A common alternative to suggested actions is cards. You can put actions in any of [the cards Teams supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference), but if you just need actions and no other features then I recommend using hero cards because they're the simplest. You can refer to [sample 6](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/06.using-cards) to see how to use cards. The code to create the activity containing your card might look something like this:

```js
var reply = MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.heroCard(null, null, ['Today', 'Tomorrow']));
```

If you want to have your buttons show up as a card in Teams but as suggested actions in Emulator then you can use `ChoiceFactory.forChannel` but you'll still need a way to keep the suggested actions from disappearing when the next message is sent. The way to do this would be to include the suggested actions as part of the prompt instead of the activity sent before the prompt.

```js
if (!step.values.flightBookingDate) {
    let promptData = {
        prompt: ChoiceFactory.forChannel(step.context, ['Today', 'Tomorrow'], "For what day do you want to book the flight? Below are the suggested date options:"),
        retryPrompt: ChoiceFactory.forChannel(step.context, ['Today', 'Tomorrow'], "No flights avaliable for that day. Please enter a different date. Below are the suggested date options:")
    };
    
    return await step.prompt(DATETIME_PROMPT, promptData);
```